# "Pixelated" charts when using the vowel package

Tags: diagrams, linguistics

I'm using the `vowel` package and the charts look "pixelated", like this:
[image: "pixelated" vowel chart]
The charts [here](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/tipa/tipaman.pdf) look perfectly fine to me, but when I generate the manual by copying the source code from [here](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/tipa/tipa/doc/vowel.tex), I get the same thing:
[image: same thing when I generate the manual]
Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{vowel}
\begin{document}
\begin{vowel}
\end{vowel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps for Installing Type1 fonts mentioned in page 3 of the [TIPA Manual](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/tipa/tipaman.pdf)?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the `vowel` and `tipa` packages? You could [create the vowel diagram using `tikz`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240585/42880), which would allow you to [use Unicode IPA symbols rather than `tipa`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240621/42880).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vowel` package does produce very pixelated diagrams, and as far as I know there's no way to use the package and avoid this. To illustrate this, I zoomed in on the diagram on p. 1 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tipa/tipa-1.3/doc/vowel.pdf):
[image]

Instead of using `vowel`, I recommend using [`tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), a powerful graphics package with extensive documentation and a supportive community of users on this site. Here's an example for the basic vowel chart:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (hf) at (0,3); % the high front vertex
\coordinate (hb) at (4,3); % the high back vertex
\coordinate (lb) at (4,0); % the low back vertex
\coordinate (lf) at (2,0); % the low front vertex

\draw (hf) -- (hb) -- (lb) -- (lf) -- cycle; % draws the trapezoid

\draw ($(hf)!1/3!(lf)$) -- ($(hb)!1/3!(lb)$); % the high-mid line
\draw ($(hf)!2/3!(lf)$) -- ($(hb)!2/3!(lb)$); % the low-mid line
\draw ($(hf)!0.5!(hb)$) -- ($(lf)!0.5!(lb)$); % the center line
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The resulting image is much less pixelated than the one made with `vowel`:

[image]

For discussion of how to place vowels on this chart, see [TikZ/PGF linguistics vowel chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240585/42880).

Comment: Unfortunately `vowel` doesn't use `picture` mode, so it can't benefit from `pict2e`.